# Inconsistent Results with PutInClipboard Method

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I have a spreadsheet set up with large text entries stored for selective copy-and-paste into another application; I am trying to devise a simple way for the user to (selectively) copy the text from any cell into the Clipboard, so that they can easily paste it into another application; all the while protecting the integrity of the source material.

The following code WORKS as desired:

```
 **Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
     Dim OutputObject    As DataObject
     Dim CellText        As String

     CellText = Target.Text
     Set OutputObject = New DataObject
     OutputObject.SetText CellText
     OutputObject.PutInClipboard

 End Sub**
```

However, the result of the double-click leaves the cellpointer inside the cell (in EDIT mode), which puts the contents of the cell at risk of being overwritten.
Inserting "CANCEL = True" should solve the problem by cancelling the effects of the double-click, leaving the cell SELECTED but not in EDIT mode.  However this results in the Clipboard being empty as nothing pastes into the outside application (Notepad).

The exact same code -- for some inexplicable reason -- DOES NOT work as expected within the Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) subroutine!?!?!

I have also tried creating an ActiveX button on the spreadsheet; the button uses relative direction logic to determine which cell's text to copy, but AGAIN ... nothing pastes into the outside application (Notepad).

Any thoughts?

Comment: `CANCEL = True` should solve the problem. But, of course, this line must be the last one. How do you test and deduce that the Clipboard is empty? It works perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

### Using SendKeys in an Event Procedure

- [`SendKeys statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement)
- You could add the following to your `Worksheet BeforeDoubleClick event` code.

**The Code**

```
 With Application
     .ScreenUpdating = False
     .SendKeys "{ENTER}{UP}"
     .ScreenUpdating = True
 End With
```